# extend scope of inner var into another function

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm sure you've gone through this a lot of times, but I cannot figure out a thread witch really fits for my needs.

How can I get var inner to work in outertwo?

```
function outerOne(){

/* do something*/

    var inner = function(){
            return true 
    }; inner();

};
outerOne()


function outerTwo(){
    if (inner==true)
/* do something*/
};
outerTwo();
```

please note, I know it would be possible to declare var x outside to make it global.
but what I like to achieve is to get the var out of the scope from inside the function

Comment: What's the question? and why do you want to use other scope variable?

Comment: I want to make var x in outerTwo() work

for example if I need to do if/else in outerTwo, which relies on x or something like that

but how can I extend the scope of inner?

Comment: I think you might be confusing variable declaration and variable assignment. Variables can be declared outside of the scope that they are assigned in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var x;
function outerOne(){

    /* do something*/

    var inner = function(){
        x = 5
        console.log(x + "  Works in inner()");       
    }; 
    inner();

    console.log(x + "  Works in outerOne()");
};
outerOne();

function outerTwo(){
    console.log(x + "  Works in outerTwo()");
};
outerTwo();
```

Functions only share scope with variables declared in their parent scopes.

**EDIT**

For completeness sake I might add that nothing is preventing you from returning values form your functions:

```
function outerOne(){

    /* do something*/

    var inner = function(){
        var x = 5
        console.log(x + "  Works in inner()");
        return x;       
    }; 
    var x1 = inner();

    console.log(x1 + "  Works in outerOne()");
    return x1;
};
var x2 = outerOne();

function outerTwo(){
    console.log(x2 + "  Works in outerTwo()");
};
outerTwo();
```

Comment: :)

I know that I could make it global this way, but what if I am not able to declare a var outside, because it  resulting during the function (please referr to my comment above)

Comment: Variables are declared by you, they do not result from functions. Functions return values that can be assigned to variables, but you are in control of when the variables are declared.

Comment: I agree and I described it quit bad, thought this would be more easy
please see my edits above

Comment: If what you are trying to say is that the variable declaration (not just the assignment) absolutely must happen within the inner function then I am sorry to inform you that you will not be able to use that variable anywhere else outside of that function.

Comment: great that's the answer I was looking for, even if I hoped there was a way to make it work, thank you

Comment: Depending on how close your example matches your actual problem, my edited solution may help you out.

Comment: awesome!
my mistake was that I just did var x1 = inner(); and tried to use it outside the outerOne

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can restructure your code to something like this

```
var obj = 
    {
        outerOne : function(){return true;//or whatever logic you need here
                          },

        outerTwo : function(){  
           if(this.outerOne() === true){
               //do something
           }
        }
    }

    obj.outerTwo();
```

Comment: ok for this case it would work, but there are some other cases were it does not

for example if the var in inner results because of an event


elem.onclick = function (){
          var inner = function(){
                return true
          }

}

function outer(){
if(inner==true)
*/ do something/*
}

Comment: If the variable is global it will be accessible from any function - including click events. Not sure I fully understand the problem

Comment: I think I described it a bit bad, so please see my edits on the function

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). And set inner as an undefined variable at the top.

```
(function(){
var inner;

  function outerOne(){
  /* do something*/

      inner = function(){
         return true 
      }; inner();
  };
  outerOne()

  function outerTwo(){
      if (inner==true){
        //inner has been set to true, do something
      }
      else{
        //Inner has not been set to true, do something else
      }
  };
  outerTwo();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variable 'x' global outside function.

```
var x = 0; 
function outerOne(){   
 //code block

var inner = function(){
        x = 5
       console.log(x + "  Works in inner()");       
}; inner();
console.log(x + "  Works in outerOne()");
};
outerOne()


function outerTwo(){
console.log(x + "  Works in outerTwo()");
};
outerTwo();
```

Comment: but what if x results because of something that happens to outerfunction, like onclick?